# Is there an equivalent to JavaScript parseInt in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, integer, parseint

I was wondering if anyone had put together something or had seen something equivalent to the JavaScript parseInt for C#.

Specifically, i'm looking to take a string like:

```
123abc4567890
```

and return only the first valid integer

```
123
```

I have a static method I've used that will return only the numbers:

```
public static int ParseInteger( object oItem )
    {
        string sItem = oItem.ToString();

        sItem = Regex.Replace( sItem, @"([^\d])*", "" );

        int iItem = 0;

        Int32.TryParse( sItem, out iItem );

        return iItem;
    }
```

The above would take:

```
ParseInteger( "123abc4567890" );
```

and give me back

```
1234567890
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to do with a regular expression, or if there is a better method to grab just the first integer from the string.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, they were all very helpful. I marked leppie's as accepted because it was first by a bit and did work. I took his and ran with that with some modifications. Jon Skeet's is definitely the most complete. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are close.

You probably just want:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"^\d+"))
{
  return int.Parse(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: That will convert "ab12cd" to 12 won't it? That may well be the desired behaviour - I'm not sure. I'm only asking because my version only works if the number is at the start of the string.

Comment: Ahh, you are right, a ^ at the start of the RE qould probably be good enough :) Thanks

Comment: leppie: I wasn't suggesting that was required, so much as that your implementation's behaviour may well be desirable, and I wanted to check :)

Comment: You can't use var in that foreach because Regex.Matches returns a MatchCollection that is a non generic ICollection. As it happens I blogged about this yesterday: http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2009/06/09/no-var-for-me-in-the-foreach

Answer (score 9):

Here's a complete example. It will throw an exception if you don't give it a valid string - you can change this behaviour by not explicitly throwing an exception in `ParseInteger`, and using `int.TryParse` instead.

Note that it allows a leading - sign as well, but not a leading +. (Again, easy to change.)

Also note that although I've got three test cases for success situations, I haven't got any test cases for failure.

Finally, it won't match "abc123def". If you want it to, remove the ^ from the regex.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Check("1234abc", 1234);
        Check("-12", -12);
        Check("123abc456", 123);
    }

    static void Check(string text, int expected)
    {
        int actual = ParseInteger(text);
        if (actual != expected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected {0}; got {1}", expected, actual);
        }
    }

    private static readonly Regex LeadingInteger = new Regex(@"^(-?\d+)");

    static int ParseInteger(string item)
    {
        Match match = LeadingInteger.Match(item);
        if (!match.Success)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Not an integer");
        }
        return int.Parse(match.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me, if there's any difference in the runtime/performance between yours, accepted and mine? does internally regex works exactly the way i posted?

Comment: You'd have to benchmark it to find out the performance. I don't know the details of how .NET regexes are implemented. It will depend on the options though - in this case I haven't specified that it should be compiled, which would probably help performance after the initial hit of compilation.

Comment: as you wrote a benchmark-suite: would you possibly run this test in some free time for me?

Comment: That benchmark suite is still very much under development, I'm afraid. With the revisions for C# in Depth for the second edition, I don't really have any spare time for this at the moment. Sorry :(

Comment: ah ... that's ok ... i'll have a look at it on my own, when i got time!

Answer (score 2):

A slight change to Jon Skeet's excellent solution is in order.

I would change the regex to (as mentioned by Jon):

`@"^([^\d]+)?(+|-)?\d+"`

This allows for the case of leading characters ahead of the first occurrence of a digit
(e.g., `asb12354` -> `12354`) and both signed integer cases (e.g. `+` or `-`)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int ParseInteger( object oItem )
    {
            int iItem = 0;
            if (oItem != null) {
                    Int32.TryParse( Regex.Match( oItem.ToString(), @"\d+" ).Value, out iItem );
            }
            return iItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this RegEx ("\A\d+") to find numbers at the beginning of a string.

You can then use int.Parse() to convert that string into an actual integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nr = Int32.Parse(yourstring);
```

Answer (score -3):

You DON'T have to write your own int parse function!!!!

I know this thread is pretty old. but there are some simple way to do this:

```
int.Parse(urString);
use short.Parse(urString); //if you want a short
```

Or:
//use those depend on your situation:

```
Convert.ToInt16();
Convert.ToInt32();
Convert.ToInt64();
```

NOTE:
I am answering your Topic Question "Is there an equivalent to JavaScript parseInt in C#?", just give you some idea, NOT write your code for you. You need to first do a filtering on 'Alphabetical Characters', you can do it with Regular Expression or a simple string.Replace, or up to you.

Comment: All of these will fail given the sample string "123abc4567890", hence the need for something custom.

Comment: I am answering your Topic Question "Is there an equivalent to JavaScript parseInt in C#?", just give you some idea, NOT write your code for you. You need to first do a filtering on 'Alphabetical Characters', you can do it with Regular Expression or a simple string.Replace, or up to you.